# Selective Validation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, textarea

I have a form that have many text fields and all are being validated, I also added the NiceEdit plugin to be able to format text in my text areas, but it is raising errors like:

**A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client**

Now I can simply go to the top of the page and in the page directive add `ValidateRequest="false"`  but this will deprive me from all the validation that I really need, so how can I switch validation OFF for my text areas ???

VB.net, ASP.net 3.5, VWD 2008 Express...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ValidateRequest` setting turns off/on built-in validation against a predefined set of dangerous values. HTML strings are considered dangerous because they could potentially be used to submit and initiate XSS/HTML injection attacks.

Your question appears to imply that you have mistaken this property to have an effect on the validation controls of your page. That is not accurate.

Since you presumably want to allow users to submit HTML via the "NiceEdit" plugin, I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. Turn off `ValidateRequest` for the page and handle validation manually. Check for the dangerous values before the form is submitted.
2. Keep `ValidateRequest` on for the page, but on the client, just before the page is submitted, use Javascript to encode the HTML value in the relevant textarea (if necessary, perform a Regex replace on all "<" and ">" characters) and then only allow a submit.

The latter method is demonstrated on [Mads Kristensen's](http://madskristensen.net/post/Re-enable-request-validation-in-ASPNET.aspx) blog and [here](http://dustyreagan.com/how-to-submit-html-without-disabling/).

Comment: Great answer mate, indeed, i fixed it, turns that i thought it will cause all validation to be switched off, but it doesn't affect it...thanks

Comment: Most welcome and thanks for the acceptance! I'm glad I was able to correctly guess that you were concerned about page level validations. ;-)

Comment: Great explanation specially for option 2!